# can't find run as junit test in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I created a test class in Eclipse like this

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration
@Transactional
public class TeamTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

 @Test
 public void testCreate() {


  assert (true);
 }}
```

However, when I click right click on the file I don't see option to run as JUnit!

What is wrong?

I am using Eclipse 3.6

Comment: What import is specified to load the Test annotation?  i.e., make sure it is 'import org.junit.Test'

Comment: @Pace: "extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests" is enough to testable in Eclipse.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Make sure your eclipse environment is using JUnit 4. JUnit 3 doesn't make use of annotations (it uses the old `extends TestCase` style)

There are few things to double check:

`Window > Preferences > Java > JUnit`

Are you seeing `junit4` or `junit3` imports? If that looks good, make sure the project itself is using JUnit4 instead of JUnit3.

`Right Click on project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries`

Is JUnit4 included there? Is anything JUnit related there? If JUnit3 is in there, click on it and click `Remove`. Then click `Add Library...` and follow the prompts from there to add JUnit again.

Out of curiosity, are the JUnits run outside of eclipse? Like with a `mvn install` or whatever build target you have for Ant that'll run JUnits

Comment: Even if you are on JUnit 4+ , if your test "extends testCase"  it wont find the @Test annotations - remove the exdends.

Answer (score 5):

The way I fixed it is by changing Test runner in the Run Configuration from the default Junit3 to Junit4. Once I made this change I could see the option Junit when I right clicked on the test class and expanded Run As[image]

Comment: In addition to the answer given by chaitanyabhatt - Select junit4 as TestRunner for **whole project** - Add junit4 in java build path (following suggestion given on error @Test annotation)

Answer (score 4):

Write a simple test case to see if Eclipse works correctly or not. If simple test case can be run, check your testcase, especially import classes.

Or make a try in "Run" -> "Run Configurations",fill the "Test class" as "`TeamTest`"(full class name). Then click "Run", see what will happen...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and verified all the settings (above mentioned) are fine. A small change (version to 1.5.21.RELEASE from 2.5.0-M2) in pom.xml resolved my issue (below). This Iam able to recreate consistently.

**STS Details**
Version: 3.9.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201707061823
Platform: Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.0)

**Pom.xml change**

**FROM**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
         **<version>2.5.0-M2</version>**
         <relativePath/> <!--  lookup parent from repository  -->
</parent>
```

**TO**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        **<version>1.5.21.RELEASE</version>**
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are using Junit as your testing framwork and not something like TestNg which cover most of Junit's purpose.